# Finding values of x for which series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $a_n = (-1)^n \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For which values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does this series converge?

I applies ratio test and get 1, which does not imply anything clearly. I am not sure if root test does any help or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This converges for all values of $x$. And we compute exactly what it converges to through some algebraic manipulation.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{ (-1)^n}{n^2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-x^2\eta(2)-\eta(1)=\frac{-\pi^2}{12}x^2-\ln(2)$$

Where $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}/n^s$ which is the [dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Particular_values). Here's a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vyqhwxzgpb).

Answer (score 0):

The series $$\sum _{n=1} ^\infty a_n= \sum _{n=1} ^\infty(−1)^n\frac { x^2+n}{n^2} $$ satisfies all the conditions of a convergent alternating series thus it converges for all values of $x\in R$

Comment: "all the conditions" meaning $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: The absolute value of term is decreasing and converges to zero.